# Doubts about Fourier transform of IR spectroscopy

Tags: fourier-transform, spectroscopy

I was studying a Michelson interferometer for infrared absorption in Fourier transform and I've found these two images (taken from [https://pages.mtu.edu/~scarn/teaching/GE4250/ftir_lecture_slides.pdf](https://pages.mtu.edu/%7Escarn/teaching/GE4250/ftir_lecture_slides.pdf) ) representing an infrared monochromatic beam of light going into the interferometer and the resulting interferogram which is of course a cosine function and two monochromatic beams of light going into the interferometer which has the resulting interferogram.

With focus to the second interferogram, when the "optical path difference" (OPD from now on) is equal to $0$ of course we have a maximum of the intensity since both beams interfere constructively and when the movable mirror is moved so that the OPD is equal to $\frac{\lambda_1}{2}$ where $\lambda_1$ is the wavelenght of one of the beams, this one interfere desctructively with his part that traveled on the other path eliminating each other and the beam of wavelenght $\lambda_2$ also interfere with his part so that we get an intensity $\neq 0$ but smaller then the first one obtained when $OPD=0$.

My question is:

At some points in the interferogram we see that total intensity of light is zero, in my opinion we get zero intensity when the movable mirror is placed at a point such that the OPD is equal to $(n+\frac{1}{2})\lambda$ for both beams, but this condition is only possible if $\lambda_1=n\lambda_2$ with $n$ being an integer, **is this the only condition in which we get total intensity equal to zero?**

**Are we always sure that there will be a certain position for the movable mirror such that the total intensity is equal to zero?**

[image]

Comment: This question is unclear. When the path difference is $n\lambda$ you get constructive interference and when PD$=(n+\frac 12 )\lambda$ you get destructive interference. Is that what you're asking, because you seem to have answered your question. If you move the mirror in the interferometer, you are changing the PD so that you will see points of constructive and destructive interference. So you will always be able to find a point (by moving the mirror) so that the waves are out of phase by a half-integer multiple of $\lambda$ (destructive interference).

Comment: @josephh I'm referring to the second image, I have two monochromatic beams with different frequencies and I'm wondering wheter both beams interfere destructively, not just one.

Comment: @Salmone it would depend on the input spectrum and some details aspects of the spectrometer. But  yes, if mathematically for the two beams if the Fourier transform goes to zero at a point you would not have any photons there at the detector. You could call that destructive interference. For real instruments you would be concerned about the coherence of the sources and worry about the contrast or fringe visibility, so it may be harder for a real instrument to how completely to zero.

Comment: @UVphoton Hi, but my question is: when the total intensity is equal to zero? What is the condition?

Comment: Do the math. You have two frequencies w1 and w2 add them together. You may want to give them a Gaussian line-shape but take the Fourier transform  and plot it out. On that axis you should get a figure like your second figure b. Think carefully of what the axis of your plot is.  The total intensity on the detector will go to zero where your plot goes to zero. The axis of your plot if you think about it can be related to the distance the mirror moved or the optical path length of the light traveled.

Comment: @UVphoton Sorry I really can't understand the sentence, why do I have to give them a Gaussian line-shape? Don't they have a cosine-like shape? But if I add two cosined I obtain anothe rcosine function